# UITableView header view covering first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to wrap my head around what could be causing an error I'm seeing. Here's how the general flow looks: when we first hit this feature, we set our `tableHeaderView` to a custom `segmentedcontrol` view, then make a service call to fetch some data, when that is complete, we reload the table. This data is all cached, so when the user leaves and comes back, no service call is made, is simply returns back the cached data. However, when coming back, it doesn't seem to recognize that a header view is on the table, and instead places the tableView at the same origin as its header view, so the first cell is covered by the headerView. Here's some relevant methods:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.useAdaptableFeedbackFooter = true
    self.tableView.registerReusableCell(DCManagePaymentsTransactionCell.self)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.segmentedControlView

    self.segmentedControlView.selectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegment.rawValue
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // TODO: Remove once we have other segments implemented
    makeServiceCall()
}

private lazy var segmentedControlView: DMSegmentedControlTableHeaderView = {
    let view = DMSegmentedControlTableHeaderView.loadableViewFromNib()
    let segmentTitles = [DCManagePaymentsString.Summary.localized, DCManagePaymentsString.History.localized, DCManagePaymentsString.Pending.localized]

    view.segmentTitles = segmentTitles
    view.delegate = self
    return view
}()

private func makeServiceCall() {
    self.businessService.getData {
        (result: DMServiceResult<DCPendingPayments>) -> Void in
        switch result {
        case .Success (let data):
            if data.isHAMode {
                self.data.payment = data.pendingPayments.first
                self.tableView.dataSource = self.HADataSource
                self.tableView.delegate = self.HADataSource
            } else {
                self.data.pendingPayments = data.pendingPayments
                self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
                self.tableView.delegate = self.dataSource
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case .Failure(let errorInfo):
            self.navigationController?.handleError(errorInfo, withCompletion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference I can see is how quickly we eventually call `reloadData()`. When I set an explicit `reloadData()` call in `viewDidAppear` it sets the `tableView` up correctly, but there's a jerky animation to that.

It seems that I may be setting my table up **too fast** for it to recognize that there's a header view? Although it doesn't make sense that that's what's causing this. Any ideas or suggestions? I can post more code if necessary.

Edit: I've added two screenshots, first is what the header looks like on first load, second is after you return and it just gets cached data (the Pending Payments is my first cell, and it gets completely covered by the header segmented control in the cached data load):

[image: First Load]

[image: Cached Load]